# IBM DB2 native encryption applied on live database

Tags: sql, database, encryption, db2

Is it possible to encrypt a db2 database using native encryption while it's in use? If so, how? I know about backup, drop, and restore but is it possible without dropping and restoring since the database is live?

Comment: No it's not possible, not at this time anyway.

Comment: Please check this video if this is what you are looking for: http://www.idug-db2.com/?commid=143131 -   An Overview of the New DB2 Native Encryption Capability